# Pulling results from two tables if first table has no matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to create a stored procedure that I can use to search for people by  first name and last name. The Fname and Lname are stored together in two different tables, looking to pull from `Table1` and if there isn't a match then pull from `Table2` the results.

```
@FName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
@LName VARCHAR(20) = NULL,

SELECT  TB1.ID, TB1.FName, TB1.LName

FROM    Table1 TB1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 TB2
          ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID

WHERE   1=1
        AND COALESCE(TB1.Fname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@FName, TB1.Fname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
        AND COALESCE(TB1.Fname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@LName, TB1.Fname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
```

What i tried so far was this and it seems to pull back all the recordes.

```
WHERE   1=1
        AND COALESCE(TB1.Fname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@FName, TB1.Fname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
        OR COALESCE(TB2.Fname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@FName, TB2.Fname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
        AND COALESCE(TB1.Lname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@LName, TB1.Lname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
        OR COALESCE(TB2.Lname, '')  LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COALESCE(@LName, TB2.Lname, ''), ' ', '%') + '%'
```

Any help or guidance would be grateful, I've google for the last day or so but i guess I am googling the wrong stuff.

Comment: You probably want to move the WHERE conditions to the ON clause.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Full Join, making sure that you coalesce the results so that it pulls from whichever table has the data.

```
SELECT  Coalesce(TB1.ID, TB2.ID) As ID, 
        Coalesce(TB1.FName, TB2.FName) As FName, 
        Coalesce(TB1.LName,TB2.LName) As LName
FROM    Table1 TB1
        Full JOIN Table2 TB2
          ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID
```

Comment: That's a different way at looking at it, ill have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it for a while and looking at what G Mastros posted, it got me thinking about how I was trying to call two `OR` statements when really all I needed was one. So i changed the `COLESCE` statement a little and put them in one `OR` which in return gave me the required results.

I feel this is a works with the ability to add other request along the way as needed, so for instance if i need to search based off of Email or phone number.

```
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LName VARCHAR(100)

SET @FName = 'Adam'
SET @LName  = NULL,

SELECT  TB1.ID,
        COALESCE(TB1.FName,TB2.FName) AS FirstName
       ,COALESCE(TB1.LName,TB2.LName) AS LAstName

FROM    Table1 TB1
        INNER JOIN Table2 TB2
          ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID

WHERE   1=1
    AND
        (
         COALESCE(U.Unit_Owner_FName, '')  LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@FName, U.Unit_Owner_FName, '') + '%'
            AND COALESCE(U.Unit_Owner_LName, '')  LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@LName, U.Unit_Owner_LName, '') + '%'

        OR

        COALESCE(I.Insured_FName, '')  LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@FName, I.Insured_FName, '') + '%'
            AND COALESCE(I.Insured_LName, '')  LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@LName, I.Insured_LName, '') + '%'
        )
```